# glPushMatrix() / glPopMatrix() doesn't affect blending states. Why is this?

Tags: opengl-es

I've been trying to get OpenGL-ES to do something roughly like the following to see if glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() could be used to put things such as blending states back how they were before glPushMatrix() was called.

It works for rotation/translation stuff - why doesn't it work for some other things such as blend states?

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); //<-first blend mode

glPushMatrix();

glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); //<-second blend mode

//...drawing and stuff here...

glPopMatrix(); 

//at this point it appears the second blend mode is still in effect - why?
```

Am I properly confused or is there another pop/push combination of functions for states not popped/pushed by glPopMatrix() and glPushMatrix()?

Is there another way to easily set *everything* back to a previous state? Thanks for any illumination!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A stack for attributes does not exist for OpenGL-ES, sorry.

You can write one yourself if you really want to. All attributes are gettable, so any stack-datastructure would do.

Imho a better way is to define a hand full of useful blending presets and have a little state-machine that allows you to switch from one blending mode to another using the least calls into OpenGL-ES. After all - how many different blendmodes do you really need?

Comment: True. I was hoping there was some way to reset blend modes, colors, all of it in one go. Seems I may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, OpenGL is a state machine and the various glPush and glPop functions control stacks. Now, there are multiple stacks. The matrix stack contains only the coordinate transformations. There is another stack, called the attribute stack, which does contain your blend function setting. Check out [glPushAttrib](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/glPushAttrib/).

Comment: There's no glPushAttrib() in OpenGL-ES :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glGet()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) to get all blending options. Then you can use them to restore the blending state.